# Как сделать систему добавление друзей?

Tags: php

В данный момент я создал таблицы "friends" с полями friend_one, friend_two, status.
 таблицу "updates" с полями update_id, update, user_id_fk, created, ip. "friends" с полями  friend_one, friend_two, status. и в таблице users добавил поле friend_count.

Дальше не знаю, что делать, как делать, покажите хотя бы пример...

Comment: таблица users c полями username, password, ip и тд. 
таблица friends с полями user_id, friend_user_id, created, status

Comment: Да, это уже есть. Просто я не понимаю как это сделать, проще говоря не понимаю этот язык.

Comment: Ну так если не знаешь языка, зачем начинать на нем писать! Сначала изучи, если нет желания/возможности, но позарез нужен сайт, найми разраба за деньги или попробуй использовать готовые решения (всякие там CMS, конструкторы сайтов и тд)